# async / await TCP listener saving images from cameras

Tags: c#, image, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

Hi guys I have a big problem: I have createad a windows form that worked as a Server listening for TCP messages sended by some cameras connected to the same private network.
Each camera send a tcp message to the server when the camera detects something, the server has to work continuosly without freezing the gui interface and has to process every TCP message. The processing of this data includes the saving of an image shooted by the sender camera. The server saves these images into a folder and here there is my problem:
the server is not able to save correclty each image: it looks like that some bytes have been lost during the trasmission but I think that all the bytes have riched the server, something deeper has happend. Maybe it could be the way that I have programmed the async / await server?

I have a list of TcpListener because I have to use more server, one for each tab.

Here how the saved images look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgK76.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/onsAa.jpg

As you can see is not completely saved, except someone for some unkown reason
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS0rk.jpg

```
    public void TcpServer(int port)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = null;
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily ==
              AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
                _listener.Add( new TcpListener(ipAddress, port));
                ReceiveDataAsync();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ipAddress == null)
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server");

    }

    private async void ReceiveDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener[tbServer.SelectedIndex].Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var tcpClient = await _listener[tbServer.SelectedIndex].AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                ReadDataFromClientAsync(tcpClient);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errore: ", e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadDataFromClientAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream=client.GetStream())
            {
                int selectedTabIndex, indexOfPort;
                string endPoint;
                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    var countBytes = new byte[4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        count = await stream.ReadAsync(countBytes, 0, countBytes.Length);
                    }
                    //The data dimension of the TCP message is into his header, 24th byte.
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[BitConverter.ToUInt32(countBytes, 0)];
                    await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


                    indexOfPort = Settings.getIndexOfPort(client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                    endPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    selectedTabIndex = Settings.getIndexOfPort(client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                    updateGui("entry", indexOfPort,endPoint);

                    BufferData bufferService = new BufferData();
                    CameraMessage cameraMessage = await bufferService.writeBufferData(bytes.ToList());
                    if (cameraMessage == null)
                        return;

                  //doing some stuff

                        msgToShow = await bufferService.SaveImageFromCamera(cameraMessage);
                      //doing other stuff  

                    }
                    client.Close();
                    closeCommunication(selectedTabIndex,indexOfPort,endPoint);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            updateGui("stop");
        }

    }
```

The BufferData class:

```
             public class BufferData
            {
              public async Task<CameraMessage> writeBufferData(List<byte> bytesList)
          {
        CameraMessage cameraMessage = new CameraMessage();

        try
        {
            int num = 0;
            int startSubData = 0;
            for (int startData = 0; startData < bytesList.Count-8; startData = startSubData + num)
            {

                int codeDataMessage = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytesList.GetRange(startData, 4).ToArray(), 0);
                int indexDataSize = startData + 4;
                int SizeDataMessage = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytesList.GetRange(indexDataSize, 4).ToArray(), 0);
                startSubData = indexDataSize + 4;
                byte[] array = bytesList.GetRange(startSubData, SizeDataMessage).ToArray();
                num = 0;
                switch (codeDataMessage)
                {
                    case 14020:
                        cameraMessage.image = await this.Base64ToImage(array);
                        num = this.OffSetStringType(SizeDataMessage);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return cameraMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> SaveImageFromCamera( CameraMessage cameraMessage)
    {
        string path = Settings.pathFolder + cameraMessage.ld_I_SN + @"\Images\";
        string res;
        if (!Directory.Exists(Settings.pathFolder+cameraMessage.ld_I_SN))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Settings.pathFolder + cameraMessage.ld_I_SN + @"\Images");
        }
            try
            {
            await Task.Run(() => { cameraMessage.image.Save(path + cameraMessage.ld_I_FILENAME, ImageFormat.Jpeg); });
                res = "#3 - OK - IMMAGINE SALVATA CON SUCCESSO";
                 cameraMessage.image.Dispose();
            return res;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                res = "#3 - ERR - IMMAGINE NON SALVATA";
            return res;

        }


    }


    public async static Task<Image> Base64ToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    }


}
```

Comment: So you are sending how many bytes the image is to the server, so it knows how much it can read. question 2, why are you converting it to base64?. also this has nothing to do with asyc and await seemingly

Comment: Why is it that you read the first 24 bytes but keep only the 20-24 and then call `BitConverter.ToUInt32(countBytes, 0)` with those last 4 bytes?

Comment: It looks like you are send a four byte header to each image that contains the byte count.  These four bytes do NOT get put into the cameraMessage.  But then in the message processing you skip the four bytes which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I am following that has this TCP header https://ibb.co/c8tJ3fD As you can see bytes from 20 to 24 are for the size of the data message so I convert that for byte for creating my buffer to read the message. Into the data message each field trasmitted follows this schema https://ibb.co/d4L4D75

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is that you're assuming a socket read will read all the bytes you ask it to. That's not how socket reads work.

When you call `await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)`, the stream will read any number of bytes from `1` to `bytes.Length`. It will return the number of bytes *actually* read. You need to take this into consideration and read again as long as your buffer hasn't been read completely.

Note that this has to be done both for the header bytes *and* the payload bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your help... How can I do this? I have understood what are you saying and I thought that the problem could be something like that but I don't know how to tell c# to read untile a buffer.length bytes have been actually read

Comment: Stream read operations return the number of bytes already read. So keep reading until you've read the entire buffer length, adjusting your offset and requested read length each time by the number of bytes already read.